# No time shown until I can undo my vote for an answer

Tags: support, upvotes, undo

I accidentally up-voted an answer, I want to undo my vote.

> you last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in
>   unless this answer is edited.

Why the answer has to be edited so I can undo my vote? I just want to undo it!

Comment: You can edit the answer yourself to be able to retract your vote. It doesn't have to be a significant edit. Just add a comma or a new-line somewhere where it is appropriate.

Comment: @machine_1 Making trivial edits just for that purpose is frowned upon, to my understanding.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery OP has 2k+ rep, so they edit don't need to be reviewed and hence generally ok to do trivial edits. As making an edit to remove vote makes pretty clear whos vote it was such edit essentially serves the same purpose to deter tactical (down)voting. As long as it is once in a while event I don't think it is a problem. Indeed such edit that needs review would be rejected (also one can make good edit for the same purpose as well).

Comment: When you have full edit privileges, we do tend to look the other way, as @Alexei said, if you're genuinely doing it to correct a mistaken vote. If it becomes a pattern, where you're just oscillating that vote back and forth, then we're going to have a stern word with you. Also... please, please, *please* don't leave the post in worse shape than it was before by your edit. Find *something* you can improve, or just add a blank line to the end.